# Color Matrix in R with all Internal Color names

Tags: r, matrix, colors

I want to make a matrix that contains all colours corresponding to the colour names in R. I managed to make a matrix, however, I'm not sure what 'oldstyle' does to the matrix, and whether I have to set it at TRUE or FALSE to get the matrix that displays all the colours corresponding to the colour names. You can find the code below:

```
    colormatrix <- matrix(1:675, 27, 25)
    colormatrix
    View(colormatrix)


    image(1:nrow(colormatrix), 1:ncol(colormatrix), 
    as.matrix(colormatrix), col=colors(),
    oldstyle = TRUE)

    image(1:nrow(colormatrix), 1:ncol(colormatrix), 
    as.matrix(colormatrix), col=colormatrix(),
    oldstyle = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think the bigger problem you have is that you are plotting `length(colors())` 657 color values in 675 spaces.

Comment: If you set `cols = colors(); length(cols) = 675` (padding the end of `cols` with `NA`) and then use `col = cols`, you'll plot the correct number of colors and there is no difference whether you set `oldstyle` to true or false.

Comment: You may be interested in this reference: http://research.stowers.org/mcm/efg/R/Color/Chart/